# Places API showing result based on IP address

Tags: api, google-places-api, google-places

I am trying to use the places API to return a list of hospitals based on the location and radius parameter.

It is working fine when the request is something like

`https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/textsearch/json?query=hospitals&radius=1000&location=18.921984,72.832465&key=YOUR_API_KEY`

But whenever I use words like **near me** or **nearby** in the query parameter the results are based on the IP address from where the request is originated.Example-

`https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/textsearch/json?query=hospitals+near+me&radius=1000&location=18.921984,72.832465&key=YOUR_API_KEY`

How can I specify to google that the results should be strictly based on the location parameter and not on the IP address from where the request has been generated.

Comment: I get 20 results with the first query. So what's wrong with it? Why would you add "near me" or any other undocumented query text along with your request? You are passing a location and a radius. Why would you need anything else?

Comment: The user enters the query, and it's quite common for people to add near me or nearby in their query statement